# Ошибка в андроид студии. Помогите

Tags: java, android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-
data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

не могу понять с чего он вдруг начал ругаться на манифест. Не могу понять как исправить. Если кто на опыте знаете помогите пожалуйста.

вот gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.football.fariz.football"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.daasuu:BubbleLayout:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
}
```

Вота манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.football.fariz.football"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FirstActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".adminChatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChoosSmileActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ForumListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forum_list" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: После обновления Android SDK он начал ругаться на отсутствие репозитория 27. Почему - непонятно(все установлено и обновлено).

Answer (score 2):

Открой build.gradle в твоем проекте и поправь значения (см. скриншот)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не сложно скажите на что он ругается?

Comment: что бы это ни было но помогло